# Spaces displayed as dots and tabs displayed as arrows

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In my Visual studio 2012 editor I erroneously pressed some obscure key combination (Ctrl-Alt-something or so) and now spaces are displayed as little dots and tabs are displayed as arrows.

[image]

I'd like to get rid of this, but I haven't found the corresponding option in TOOLS-Options-Text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space to rectify this. Alternatively, you may use the key combination `Ctrl + R`, `Ctrl + W`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick tip:

An efficient way to find Visual Studio options and commands is to use the "Quick Launch" feature (Ctrl+Q - or just type in the box at the top right of the Visual Studio IDE) - in this case typing "white space" or just "space" in that box shows the command you need and lets you take the action from there too.